# How to install biicode on osx command line (for travis)

Tags: macos, command-line-interface, travis-ci, biicode

I need to install biicode on travis **OSX** machines. Is it possible to install biicode from the command line on OSX?

I tried to install it with `sudo installer -pkg bii-macos-64_3_3.pkg -target /` but it fails. Triying to install it with homebrew (cask) also fails with this error.

[image: biicode fails to install]

Comment: Have you tried to install&run it from source code? It is open source, should be just git clone (two repos, client & common) and then pip install -r requirements of both.

Comment: Also, have you tried with homebrew cask? https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/biicode.rb

Comment: Hi @drodri, I tried cask and it fails with the same error. I didn't think of running it from source code. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Ok, great, tell me if you find any problem running from source.

Comment: It seems you use ElCapitan.
I have the same problem

Comment: Wait a second, so there is no fix for Mac OS-X El Capitan at this point in time?

It's December, I just tried both the installer, and brew cask, and getting the same exact error.